# How do I check a value entered?? Python 3.4

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, input, exception

```
def p_parameter(p):

     if p < 10 or p > 100:
        int(input("Please try again: "))
        newp = p
        return newp
    else:
        newp <10 or newp >100
        input("Good bye")
        bye()

def main():

        speed(0)
        R=100
        r=4
        p=int(input("Please enter a number between 10 and 100: "))
        p_parameter(p)
        t_iter(R,r,p)
        Xcord(R,r,p,t_iter(R,r,p))
        Ycord(R,r,p,t_iter(R,r,p))
        input("Hit enter to close porgram")
        bye()

main()
```

Here is my code for a program which draws a spirograph. The program runs fine but what I have posted here is my attempt to have the user enter a value between 10-100 for `p`.

What I want to do is check to see if `p` is < 10 or `p` > 100. If it is, then give the user a chance to re-enter a new value of `p` and use that value as long as it fits the allowed limits. After the second check if the user still has entered an incorrect value of `p` I want the program to close.

The problem is that it checks for 'p' then asks for `p` again but it only take the first value of 'p', and does not preform the second check or give `p` its new value.

Comment: make sure you use the return value of the function

Comment: so in p_parameter after the if/else statement I need to add return p_parameter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just prompt in the function. This is the standard idiom for writing these kinds of validations:

```
def validate():
    while True:
        # begin inf. loop
        p = input("some prompt goes here")
        if some_validation:
            break
            # end inf. loop
        # therefore if the validation fails, it reprompts
    # once you're out of the inf. loop...
    return p
```

This is one of those things you could build a pretty good decorator for

```
def validate(validation, not_valid_warning=None):
    if not hasattr(validation, '__call__'):
        raise TypeError("validation must be callable")
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped(*args):
            while True:
                p = f(*args)
                if validation(p):
                    break
                if not_valid_warning:
                    print(not_valid_warning)
            return p
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

@validate(lambda x: x < 10 or x > 100)
def v_input(*args):
    return __builtins__.input(*args)

# Example..........
if __name__ == "__main__":
    v_input("Enter a number less than 10 or more than 100: ")
```

Comment: def validate():
    while True:
        p=int(input("Please enter a number between 10 and 100: "))
        if p < 10 or p > 100:
            break
    return p                                                             so I did this put now my other function do not have p defined

Comment: in your `main` function you'll need to do `p = validate()` rather than `p = input('whatever'); validate()`

Answer (score 0):

**Problems with your solution & Corrections:**

> it only take the first value of `p` and does not give `p` its new value.

1. you ask the user for `p` again, but do not assign this new value to `newp` variable, like so:

   ```
   newp = int(input("Please try again: "))
   ```

> does not preform the second check.

2. your `else` statement is checking for condition on `newp` outside the scope of the `newp` variable, which is inside the `if` statement. You should encapsulate your check on `newp` variable inside the `if` statement, like so:

   ```
   def p_parameter(p):
       if p < 10 or p > 100:
           newp = int(input("Please try again: "))
           if newp <10 or newp >100:
   ```
3. you don't have `return` statements inside the `p_parameter()` function for the instances when the program does not enter the `if` statement. So it should instead be like this:

   ```
   def p_parameter(p):
       if p < 10 or p > 100:
           newp = int(input("Please try again: "))
           if newp <10 or newp >100:
               print( "Good Bye")
               bye()
           else: 
               return newp    # need return statements like this
       else:
           return p           # need return statements like this
   ```

**Suggested Solution to your questions**:

> What I want to do is check to see if 'p' is < 10 or 'p' > 100, if it is then give the user a chance to reenter a new value of 'p' and use that value as long as it fits within the allowed parameters.

1. use a `while True:` infinite loop with the `break` statement to exit if the correct answer is received.
2. use `try`, `except` and `else` block with the `ValueError`

   1. to catch any errors due to inputs that are not integers.
   2. to detect any inputs that are out of the allowed range.

> After the second check if the user still has entered an incorrect value of 'p' I want the program to close.

In order to close the program, you can either:

1. let the user hit `ctrl+c` (my personal preference), *or*
2. put a counter of how many times the `while` loop should be run to check for new input, and then force the program to exit if a limit is reached by using `sys.exit(0)` (Note: First You'll need to `import sys` to use it; I think your `bye()` is doing just that).

**Putting it all together:**

1. In your `main()` function, remove the `input()` statement and only have a call to `p_parameter()` function, like so:
       p = p_parameter()
2. Define `p_parameter()` function as follows:

   ```
   import sys
   def p_parameter():
       exit_counter = 1    # counter to exit after 2 tries

       while True:
           try:
               p = int( input( "Please enter a number between 10 and 100: ") )
           except ValueError:
               print( "Not a number, Try Again" )
           else:
               if 10 < p < 100:    # this is much faster than your approach
                   break           # exit the loop
               else: 
                   print( "Value not in range")

                   # increment counter to exit when 2 tries are over
                   exit_counter+=1
                   if ( counter > 2 ):
                       print( "Good Bye" )
                       sys.exit(0)  # bye()

        return p
   ```